# remove lines if statements

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
Status  ID 
  A     1
  B     1
  B     1
  A     1
  B     1
  A     1
  A     2
  A     2
  A     2
  A     2
  B     3
  B     3
  B     3
```

To illustrate my desired output, please have a look at below:

```
Status  ID 
  B     1
  B     1
  B     1
  A     2
  A     2
  A     2
  A     2
  B     3
  B     3
  B     3
```

As you can see, the only thing that changes is for group ID = 1. If a group contains both a "A" and "B" status, I'd like to remove the "A" status.

However, Group ID 2 and 3 did not change (ie no lines removed) because: if each group ID only contains a "A", then it will remain the same. Likewise, if each group ID only contains a "B", it will also remain the same. Hence both remains the same.

Using dplyr, this is my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)

df1_clean <- df1 %>% group_by(ID, Status)
                 %>% filter(ifelse((Status == A | Status == B), Status == B,
                     ifelse((Status == A), Status == A,
                     ifelse((Status == B), Status == B))))
```

However, this filter will not work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `filter` grouped by `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(Status == "A") | all(Status == "B") | Status == "B")

#   Status    ID
#   <fct>  <int>
# 1 B          1
# 2 B          1
# 3 B          1
# 4 A          2
# 5 A          2
# 6 A          2
# 7 A          2
# 8 B          3
# 9 B          3
#10 B          3
```

---

We can also use `n_distinct`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Status) == 1 | Status == "B")
```

---

Equivalent base R `ave` versions would be

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Status, ID, FUN = function(x) 
          all(x == "A") | all(x == "B") | x == "B"))), ]

df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Status, ID, FUN = function(x) 
         length(unique(x)) == 1 | x == "B"))), ]
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it is always advisable to give example in a copy friendly format using `dput(df1)` so that other can easily regenerate the data.

This task can be achieved by creating a flag column that indicates if a `ID` has multiple `Status` or not then filtering those that don't have multiple `status` or have `status == "B"`. As follows:

```
clean_df1 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(multiple = if_else(n_distinct(Status) > 1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!multiple | Status == "B") %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(- multiple)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Status    ID
   <fct>  <dbl>
 1 B          1
 2 B          1
 3 B          1
 4 A          2
 5 A          2
 6 A          2
 7 A          2
 8 B          3
 9 B          3
10 B          3
```